# Is it possible to sync or upload the file from google drive without copying the whole thing in the folder using python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I just start learning the python scripting and I created a script using pydrive and the function is uploading all files from local folder (linux OS) to google drive but I'm planning to modify the script for my automation and add the function that can upload only the most recent file added to the local folder with no reuploading of all the files inside the folder, may I know if this is possible with python script alone?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use pydrive. You can use the Google api python client library directly.   As far as i know pydrive does use the client library internally.   There's a starter example here

## [Quick start python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## [Manage uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python)

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```